# Display the latest content from subpages of another page

Tags: child-pages, advanced-custom-fields

I know how to display content from one page on another page. Here is the code I use to display the last three video-titles, submitted to my video-page, on another page (using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for the content)

```
<?php
$other_page = 5;
?>
<?php if(get_field('video', $other_page)): $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (the_repeater_field('video', $other_page)): $count++; ?>
<?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?>      
<?php if($count==3) break; ?>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But what I want to do is to display content from the last three video-subpages, and not just the content displayed on the video page itself. Does anyone know how to do this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the number param to limit the number of pages you want and get the custom field in the foreach loop :) (child of = your parent page, or the current page)

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'number' => 3, ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
      <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
   <?php
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages